# PIL installation on windows with python 3.4.2

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to do an image processing project using python and so I downloaded PIL. But i dont know how to integrated the imaging libraries with my current python installation. I have browsed a lot but couldn't find any solution. Any reference would be of big help. thanks

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library/Getting_PIL

Comment: I read that and it supports only till 2.6. Is there any alternative for PIL in python 3.4.2?

Comment: Try installing Pillow with "pip3 install Pillow", it's a wrapper around PIL and provides easier installation